# Swift error when saving a child object using core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am getting the following error when attempting to perform my save function in a view on my app. I have passed my parent object in called Vacation. I am attempting to save a child object called SavingsEntry. The app stopped and shows

```
(lldb)
```

In the console and

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x10c13b860:  pushq  %rbp
0x10c13b861:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10c13b864:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x10c13b867:  je     0x10c13b89e               ;swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10c13b869:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x10c13b873:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x10c13b876:  jne    0x10c13b89e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10c13b878:  leaq   0xb52e9(%rip), %rax
0x10c13b87f:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x10c13b882:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x10c13b885:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x10c13b890:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x10c13b893:  je     0x10c13b8ad               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x10c13b895:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x10c13b899:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x10c13b89c:  jne    0x10c13b890               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10c13b89e:  leaq   0x36b7d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10c13b8a5:  movq   %rax, 0xb4c0c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10c13b8ac:  int3   
0x10c13b8ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax   **Thread1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)**
0x10c13b8b0:  popq   %rbp
0x10c13b8b1:  retq   
0x10c13b8b2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Ive narrowed down the break is in the section where I am saving setting my object values and saving. But I can't see where the problem is.

```
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

        savingsEntry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SavingsEntry", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as SavingsEntry

        savingsEntry.vacation = vacation

        savingsEntry.created = NSDate()

        if addToSavings.text == "" {

            savingsEntry.amount = NSDecimalNumber(string: removeFromSavings.text)
            savingsEntry.type = "debit"
            vacation.totalSaved = subtraction(vacation.totalSaved, right: savingsEntry.amount)

        } else if removeFromSavings.text == "" {
            savingsEntry.amount = NSDecimalNumber(string: addToSavings.text)
            savingsEntry.type = "credit"
            vacation.totalSaved = addition(vacation.totalSaved, right: savingsEntry.amount)

        }



        var e: NSError?
        if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true {
            println("insert error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the class of the `SavingsEntry` entity to be the `SavingsEntry` class?

Comment: Yes I have  `var savingsEntry:SavingsEntry!`

Comment: I mean in the model editor, where you specify the entity name.

Comment: Ha that was it @pbasdf. The one I missed LOL...thanks!